# Electron.js has broken encoding and UTF-8 not working

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, electron, ipc

Electron.js coding UTF-8 has broken

The ipcRenderer receives the data correctly.  But that's when it sends already scary characters to the server side.  Also, in sequelize, when making requests, it is also not clear what is happening (everything works in models.js, but not in app.js anymore).  All file encodings are UTF-8

meta charset="utf-8" is in every HTML file

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly. At least include a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: UTF-8 characters turn into something incomprehensible.  UTF-8 doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Sorry, the pictures are not downloaded. I pinned the pictures now